# trying to insert a node into a tree, but it's not working

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm a little confused why my code doesn't insert nodes past the first one. say I wanted to insert (5,4) after (7,2) using the code below; in this case the very first condition is triggered, `isVertical` and `p.x() < node.point.x()`. The way I see it since `node.left` is null, I exit the loop and since `node` holds a reference `node.left` based on the latest assignment, I should be able to use `node` to insert a new tree leaf. Am I not seeing this right? Is `node` not really a reference to `node.left`? Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am still just a little shaky with references.

```
public void insert(Point2D p) {
    if (p == null) {
        throw new java.lang.NullPointerException();
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        root = new Node(p);
        size++;
        return;
    }
    Node node = root;
    while (node != null) {
        // sink
        if (node.isVertical()) {
            if (p.x() < node.point.x()) {
                node = node.left;  // go left
            } else {
                node = node.right; // go right
            }
        } else if (node.isHorizontal()) {
            if (p.y() < node.point.y()) {
                node = node.left;  // go left
            } else {
                node = node.right; // go right
            }
        }
    }
    node = new Node(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just assigning `new Node(p)` to a local variable `node`, whose value is lost as soon as the function returns. To change the existing tree, your assignment should have the form `node.left = new Node(p);` or `node.right = new Node(p)`.